# Why is all sound suddenly gone with HTC One S?

Tags: audio, htc-one-s

All of a sudden I have no sound with my HTC One S (running Android 4.1.1).
No sound is heard when someone tries to call me, and, curiously, the microphone is also muted; the one who's calling me doesn't hear anything either. I also cannot play audio (it says something like *Cannot play this type audio file*).
What on earth is going on? And how to solve it?

PS: I have not spilled coffee or something over my phone; no unusual things happend to my phone, as far as I know.

Comment: Rooted? Recent apps added? Does everything look "normal" under `Settings > Sound`?

Comment: Maybe some "Silent Mode" or profile enabled? Or (might sound stupid) headphones plugged in?

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset?

Comment: Everything looks normal under sound settings. Also, the silent profile is not active and there are no headphones plugged in. I have once applied factory defaults. Nothing helped. In addition, the phone has not been rooted.
Is it maybe a glitch in the software (either Android or HTC SDK version)?